# Flex binds to embeded Arial font variable called private var arial:String?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am embedded in my application like so:

```
[Embed(source="/assets/arial.ttf", fontName="Arial")]
private const arial:String;
```

Flex errors with the following:

warning: incompatible embedded font 'Arial' specified for mx.core::UITextField (UITextField75) . This component requires that the embedded font be declared with embedAsCFF=false.

Changing the above to private const embArial:String; gets ride of the error. Why is this? What are the internals of the explanation for this?

Changing the fontName does not resolve. Changing the variable to Arial:String does resolve. Changing to arial:Class does not resolve. Very peculiar. It appears to be bound to the variable name arial.

None of the tutorials or specifications on font really address what happens when a font embed is bound to a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your component is MX (Halo), you want embedAsCFF to be false.

For Spark components, you embedAsCFF: true.

CSS implementation:

Spark Example:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: "Myriad Web Pro";
    src: url("./assets/fonts/MyriadWebPro.ttf");
    font-weight: normal;
    embedAsCFF: true;  /* Spark */
    advancedAntiAliasing: true;
    unicodeRange: 
        U+0041-U+005A, /* Upper-Case [A..Z] */
        U+0061-U+007A, /* Lower-Case a-z */
        U+0030-U+003F, /* Numbers [0..9] */
        U+0020-U+002F, /* Space + Punctuation [ !"#$%&'()*+,-./ ] */
        U+003A-U+0040; /* Special Chars [ :;?@ ] */
}
```

MX Halo Example:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: "Myriad Web Pro";
    src: url("./assets/fonts/MyriadWebPro.ttf");
    font-weight: normal;
    embedAsCFF: false;  /* Halo */
    advancedAntiAliasing: true;
    unicodeRange: 
        U+0041-U+005A, /* Upper-Case [A..Z] */
        U+0061-U+007A, /* Lower-Case a-z */
        U+0030-U+003F, /* Numbers [0..9] */
        U+0020-U+002F, /* Space + Punctuation [ !"#$%&'()*+,-./ ] */
        U+003A-U+0040; /* Special Chars [ :;?@ ] */
}
```

With Flex, I find it easier to work with CSS for fonts.  Just link your style sheet in your main app:

```
<!--- CSS style -->
<fx:Style source="assets/css/common.css" />
```

If you prefer to embed, it should be of type `Class` for transcoding.

Embed implementation:

```
    [Embed(systemFont = "Arial", fontWeight = "Regular", fontName = "Arial", mimeType = "application/x-font", embedAsCFF = "false", unicodeRange = "U+0020-U+002F,U+0030-U+0039,U+003A-U+0040,U+0041-U+005A,U+005B-U+0060,U+0061-U+007A,U+007B-U+007E,U+00A1-U+00A1,U+00A3-U+00A3,U+00A9-U+00A9,U+00AE-U+00AE,U+00B0-U+00B0,U+00BC-U+00BE,U+00BF-U+00BF,U+00C0-U+00FF,U+2013-U+2014,U+2018-U+2019,U+201C-U+201D,U+2022-U+2023,U+2120-U+2120,U+2122-U+2122")]
    private static const Arial:Class;
```

In your Embed, add `embedAsCFF=true` or `embedAsCFF=false` for Spark or MX Halo components respectively.

Comment: I appreciate the answer and I know all this. The question was about the peculiarities of why and how flex is globally bound to a variable called arial.

Comment: I think the answer is something like this: When you embed the font (or an image), you need some place in your code to reference it. So the embedded asset is associated with a variable, that we can use in code.  Your error went away when you changed this variable to a String, I'm assuming b/c that association fails. The variable needs to be typed as a Class, so that you can later instantiate an instance of this class and reference it in your code.

Comment: It did not go away regardless of whether the variable: var arial was a String or a class. But I encourage you to NOT seek an answer as this a curiosity question not a relevant one.

Answer (score 1):

This [Adobe page has the syntax you need](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f5f.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf6320a-7ffa) to use to embed the font in Actionscript, using meta data (note, you can also embed a font using CSS).